# Import one schema into another new schema - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a data dmp file exported from one schema user1 using the `exp` commandline utility.

I want to import this dump onto another newly created (empty) schema user 2 using the `imp`  commandline utility.

I tried a few things like:

```
imp system/password@tesdb fromuser=user1 touser=user2 file=E:\Data\user1.dmp log=E:\Data\user1.log
```

I get an error

```
IMP-00002: failed to open user1.dmp for read
Import file: EXPDAT.DMP >
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the problem is with the dump file itself.  Are you sure that the file exists in the e:\data directory on the local machine?  Are you sure that the Windows user that you are logged in to has access to this file?  Does some other process have the file locked?

Comment: If you want to remap schemas, the easiest solution is to stop using `exp`/`imp` and start using the DataPump utilities: `expdp` and `impdp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the dmp file itself. I had to re-export the file and the command works fine. Thank you @Justin Cave

Answer (score 27):

After you correct the possible dmp file problem, this is a way to ensure that the schema is remapped and imported appropriately.  This will also ensure that the tablespace will change also, if needed:

```
impdp system/<password> SCHEMAS=user1 remap_schema=user1:user2 \
            remap_tablespace=user1:user2 directory=EXPORTDIR \
            dumpfile=user1.dmp logfile=E:\Data\user1.log
```

EXPORTDIR must be defined in oracle as a directory as the system user

```
create or replace directory EXPORTDIR as 'E:\Data';
grant read, write on directory EXPORTDIR to user2;
```

Comment: You cannot import a dumpfile created with `exp` using DataPump.

Comment: Oops... I did miss that they were using exp and not expdp.  I would work if it was created used expdp :P

Comment: +1 because it would be a good answer, if the dump was created using expdp.

Comment: The dump file should contain source schema and tablespaces, otherwise the mapping will not happen.