# Copy tables, packages and procedures from one schema to another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-migration

I am using an oracle database. I am accessing that database through two users. They are userA and userB. I have created some tables, packages and procedures etc. in userA schema. Here after I want to continue my work using 'userB' and remove userA.

I granted permissions from userA to userB and created a table with a separate name by selecting all records. Then I saw that triggers and indexes have not been created. I want to know the best method to copy tables, packages and procedures with data from one user to another.

Comment: Well, the actual best practice is retain scripts of your DDL including packages and procedures under source control, and run builds from those scripts. I guess that's not of much help to you now, but it's a lesson for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy tables by backing up using `expdp` and then importing using `impdp` with the `remap_schema`/`remap_tablespace` options (example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145624/1509264)).

You cannot use this method for packages, procedures or triggers as the [`impdp` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927) states that:

> ## Restrictions
>
> - The mapping may not be 100 percent complete because there are certain schema references that Import is not capable of finding. For example, Import will not find schema references embedded within the body of definitions of types, views, procedures, and packages.
> - For triggers, REMAP_SCHEMA affects only the trigger owner.

To transfer these you will have to edit the source code of the triggers/pacakages/procedures/etc. and then recompile it on the new schema so that the schema references within the code are also updated.